# Form Validation with Dependent Fields in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angular-ui

I have an object that has 2 fields, while 1 should be less than or equal to another.

Say it's HDD quota settings and I need the `threshold` to be less than or equal to HDD's `size`.

I am trying to use angular's [ui-utils#validate](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/#/validate).

This is how I got so far: http://embed.plnkr.co/EysaRdu2vuuyXAXJcJmE/preview (i hope the link will work)

The problem that I am having is that it works to one direction:

Setting `size` and then playing with `threshold` works ok

But if I try to change `size`, after `threshold` is in invalid state - nothing happens. This is because invalid `threshold` is not set on the model and `size` id being compared against `null` or `undefined` (or something like that).

On one hand I understand the logic of not setting invalid value on the model... but here it is getting in my way.

So, any help making this work will be appreciated.

Comment: This issue is being discussed here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils/issues/25

Comment: Better late than never, you need to add ng-model-options="{allowInvalid:true}" to your form input elements to stop this happening - the problem is that when the $q service rejects a response the model, by default, is not updated. Crazy huh! Cost me a day working this out.

Answer (score 6):

I have played with custom directives and cooked something that works for my case.

On my input  for `threshold` I have `less-than-or-equal="quota.size"` directive, passing it the model's property to validate against (I want `quota.threshold` to be less than or equal to `quota.size`):

```
<input type="number" name="threshold" 
    ng-model="quota.threshold" 
    required 
    less-than-or-equal="quota.size" />
```

In `link` function of `lessThanOrEqual` directive it starts to watch the `quota.size` and when `quota.size` changes it just tries to set the current view value of `threshold` on model:

```
link: (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) ->
    scope.$watch attr.lessThanOrEqual, (newValue) ->
        ctrl.$setViewValue(ctrl.$viewValue)
```

Then there is the parser that does the validation by calling `scope.thresholdValidate(thresholdValue)` method passing it the candidate value. This method returns `true` if validation succeeded and if it does - it returns the new value, otherwise - current model's value:

```
    ctrl.$parsers.push (viewValue) ->
        newValue = ctrl.$modelValue
        if not scope.thresholdValidate viewValue    
            ctrl.$setValidity('lessThanOrEqual', false)
        else
            ctrl.$setValidity('lessThanOrEqual', true)
            newValue = viewValue
        newValue
```

I am pushing the parser to parser collection, as opposite to unshifting it like most of the examples suggest, because I want angular to validate `required` and `number` directives, so I get here only if I have a valid and parsed number (less work for me, but for `text` inputs I probably should do the parsing job)

Here is my playground: http://embed.plnkr.co/EysaRdu2vuuyXAXJcJmE/preview

Answer (score 3):

Better late than never, you need to add `ng-model-options="{allowInvalid:true}"` to your form input elements to stop this happening - the problem is that when a promise is rejected (e.g. using `$q` or `$http`) the model, by default, is not updated. Crazy huh! Cost me a day working this out.

I have written a plunkr specifically for this problem - Trust me this code is good ... 
http://embed.plnkr.co/xICScojgmcMkghMaYSsJ/preview