# AngularJs validate dependent fields using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, validation

My questions is similar to [Form Validation with Dependent Fields in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798388/form-validation-with-dependent-fields-in-angularjs) however the validation has to be done on the server side with **Ajax**.

I have two fields **city** and **postal code** and want to use a backend service to tell if both fields match.
The backend service has already been implemented. So now I am trying to integrate the service with angular.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at [ui-validate](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/#/validate) from angular-ui. you can use ui-validate with a function call returning promise

so your html would be

```
      <input type="text" ng-model="city" ui-validate=" 'doMatch($value, postal)' ">
      <input type="text" ng-model="postal" ui-validate=" 'doMatch(city, $value)' ">
```

and the js should be

```
$scope.doMatch = function(c, p) {
     return $http.post("/api/validateCityPostal", {postal: p, city : c});
}
```

note that above function is returning a promise. and from server you should return success/failure to have $valid or $invalid on the ui-validate.

Comment: This looks realy nice

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS 1.3 introduced async validators. You can add a function that returns a promise to your ngModelController's [`$asyncValidators`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$asyncValidators) array, it will set the model's validity based on the value the promise is resolved with.

If you can't use 1.3 then you could always set the model to be invalid while the request is happening and set it to its final value once you get the result back from the server.

In either case the custom directive approach in the answer you linked to is probably your best bet.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use 1.2.
I guess this is the way to go for me I was hoping for a better solution but this will be good enough ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="blablabla">
   <input type="text" ng-model="city">
   <input type="text" ng-model="postal">
</form>
```

JS:

```
 angular.module("module",[]).service("validate", ['$http', function ($http){
       this.validate_postal = function (p) {
           return $http.post("/api/validate_post", {post: p});
       }

       this.validate_city= function (c){
            return $http.post("/api/city",{city: city});
       }

}]);
```

Validation service returns promise. So you can add  async callbacks latter in the controller.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to submit both in one request - the postal code and the city

Answer (score -1):

There is a great example [**here**](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/validations.html). "Custom validations" section

Comment: that example does not deal with multiple dependent fields