# Circular number validation in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I currently am working with a problem which seems like it would be a common but I am having trouble finding an elegant way to handle it.  The problem boils down to two number input fields where the one field must be less than the other field.  To perform this, I am using the following directive to validate the input to the lower input field, where scope.maxThreshold is the input to the higher input field:

```
testDirectives.directive('maxThreshold', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
                if (viewValue > scope.maxThreshold) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('thresholdTooHigh', false);
                    return undefined;
                } else {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('thresholdTooHigh', true);
                    return viewValue;
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

The directive for the higher input field is very similar with the comparison switched.  This all works well until a user switches which field they are inputting into after they receive a validation error.  For example, if the lower field is 5 and the higher field is 10 and the user switches the lower field to 15.  This field now is marked as having a validation error.  Now if the user goes to the higher input field and puts 20, the directive for that field fires and validation passes.  The problem is the validity of the lower input field is still marked as invalid.  What's the best way to handle this and to mark the lower input field as valid from the directive used for the higher input field?  Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to use something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798388/form-validation-with-dependent-fields-in-angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the issues is checking the validity of the input on an event other then its model changing. Namely, you want to also check the validity if the condition changes.  See the directive:

This is much closer to what you are looking for.  You don't seem to what to make the the max field invalid if the min field is being edited.  Another check in the watch function can accomplish that.

```
    .directive('highThreshold', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            'highThreshold': '='
        },
        link: function($scope, element, ctrl, ngModel) {
            $scope.$watch('highThreshold', function(){
                var isValid = ngModel.$modelValue < $scope.highThreshold;
                ngModel.$setValidity("highThreshold", isValid);
            });
            ngModel.$validators.highThreshold = function(value) {
                return value < $scope.highThreshold;
            };
        }
    };

})
.directive('lowThreshold', function() {

    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            'lowThreshold': '='
        },
        link: function($scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            $scope.$watch('lowThreshold', function(){
                var isValid = ngModel.$modelValue > $scope.lowThreshold;
                ngModel.$setValidity("lowThreshold", isValid);
            });
            ngModel.$validators.lowThreshold = function(value) {
                return value > $scope.lowThreshold;
            };
        }
    };

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dn9prtxx/

Sorry for not getting the question the first time :) Hope this helps!

Comment: This doesn't help.  I am looking for an example where both fields can become invalid.  The validity of your maximum field isn't dependent on the other input field.

Comment: if your problem is "The problem boils down to two number input fields where the one field must be less than the other field".  Under what condition should the maximum field become invalid?

Comment: I think i'm following you now.  You what the current field being used input being modified to become invalid based on the value of the other field.  I not seeing why this would be necessary as the order of you inputs should clarify the maximum value.  But it is an interesting problem, I'll look into it some more!

Comment: I edit my response, hopefully it is more helpful now.  Essentially I added a $watch on the condition and rechecked the validity when the condition changes